# Need help with this homogeneous diff. equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^2dx+(x^2+3xy+4y^2)dy=0$$

Substitution: $$x=vy$$ $$dx=vdy+ydv$$

Simplifying everything:

$$(v+2)^2dy+ydv=0$$

$$\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dv}{(v+2)^2}=0$$

Integrating both we obtain:

$$\frac{1}{(v+2)}+C=ln|y|$$

$$y=e^\frac{1}{v+2}C$$

That's where I think I have a mistake, since the answer looks pretty messy.

Moreover, I need to find $C$ such that $x=2 , y=1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved Very good. Good job.

Comment: Just substitute $(x,y)=(2,1)$ into the implicit equation, you can find the integration constant $C$.